# Android spinner activate on Imageclicklistener

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

Hi everybody I'm developing app that has a list and each element have Image, now i want to fix spinner on each listview(Image) element. as I click on image spinner show as drop down and spinner remain invisible in list any one help..

I'm also trying this code: and I'm extending array adapter class

```
  holder.spinner1=(Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        holder.image_view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                ((Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1)).performClick();



            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you have set spinner visibility "invisible". If so, then you need to make it visible on click of imageview. Then you can add rest functionality.

Comment: I also did but still code doesnot work because of I am using(extending) arrayadapter class therefore may be

Comment: Use holder.spinner1 instead of ((Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1)).performClick();

Comment: When you get correct answer, you should upvote to that answer. This is how stackoverflow works